# Instagram API - get all users media

Tags: php, api, instagram

Can someone tell me how I can get all media of an user with PHP? 
I use

```
 https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=
```

but there is no return of next_url in pagination. And anyway, is there any way to do it easier than with next_url?

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: you need a valid access token, and client id if you have those things you can send a valid request otherwise you need to worry about getting those things first

Comment: I do have both of these things. But I can't get a response.

Comment: can you post more code so I can better understand what you're trying to do in particular it would make it easier to help you

Comment: At the moment I only try it in the browser. So when I put in the URL I get a response to work with. I get e response, but without the pagination. 

Do I need to add any parameters to get a next_url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. Instagram API does not allow more than 20 Posts in Sandmode mode.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation at https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent you can add a `count`-param to specify the amount of media you want to fetch.

So `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=XXXX&count=9999999` should do the trick.

Comment: Did this work? The documentation is vague on what the default number of results is, and whether it can be increased in this way.